# Matlab regex - replace substring ONLY within angled brackets

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I would like to find a way to find a way to replace the character `_` inside string `s` with itself surrounded by spaces. The only difficult part is that I'm trying to replace the substring only if the substring is found inside angled brackets. For example (spaces are intentional):

`s= 'the quick <_brown _little_fox >, jumped over_the_fence .`

`wantedresult = the quick < _ brown  _ little _ fox>, jumped over_the_fence.`

If there is already space on either side, getting extra spaces is perfectly fine.

I tried the following but to no luck:
`regexprep(s, <[\w ]+(\_)[\w ]+>', ' $1 ');`

I think I understand the reason why the above doesn't work, but considering that more than one `_` may be inside brackets, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to do it in a single `regex`, why don't you try extracting all strings that are between `<>`, find those characters that have the `_` character and surround those characters with spaces, then reconstruct the final string?  I would use `regexp` first to find those areas in your string that have `<>` surrounding the string, then do what I mentioned above.... so do this first:

```
[st, en, match] = regexp(s, '<.*?>', 'start', 'end', 'match')
```

This finds all strings that have `<>` surrounding the substring.  The `start` and `end` flags determine which indices in the start and ending indices in the string that match what we're looking for.  In our case, `start` tells you where each `<` character is and `end` tells you where each `>` character is.  `match` is a cell array of strings that matches our search for `<>` substrings.  These are respectively stored in `st`, `en` and `match`.  Once we're done, let's do a `regexprep` on `match` and put spaces before and after the `_` characters.

```
final_match = regexprep(match, '_', ' _ ');
```

Now to reconstruct the final string, we first place the characters from the beginning up to the first `<` occurrence, then we'll write a loop that pieces everything all together, then when we find the last `>` character, add up all of the characters to the end.... so something like:

```
final_string = s(1:st(1)-1);
for idx = 1 : numel(final_match)-1
    final_string = [final_string final_match{idx}];
    final_string = [final_string s(en(idx)+1:st(idx+1)-1)];
end
final_string = [final_string final_match{end} s(en(end)+1:end)];
```

The first line takes stuff from the original string up until the first occurrence of the `<` character.  Next, for each substring that is between the `<>` characters (also including those characters), we place our modified string that puts spaces in between the `_` characters and then we access those characters in between the `>` character of the current substring to the `<` character of the next substring and we repeat this process until we hit the last `<` character.  Once we hit this last `<` character, we place the final `<>` modified substring, and finally piece the last of the original string at the end.  If we use the above code with your example, we get:

```
final_string = 

the quick < _ brown  _ little _ fox >, jumped over_the_fence.
```

If we modified the string `s` so we get:

```
s =

the quick <_brown _little_fox >, < _jumped _over _the_ fence>.
```

The output I get with the above code is:

```
final_string =

the quick < _ brown  _ little _ fox >, <  _ jumped  _ over  _ the _  fence>.
```

As you can see, there are spaces in between the `_` characters for all words that are between the `<>` characters.  However, this only works if there is at least one sequence of `<>` characters.  If it doesn't, then the above code doesn't work.  As such, you'll need to check if `match` (or `start` or `end`) has at least one element.  If it does, then proceed with the above code.  If it doesn't, just spit out the original string.

Comment: Single character suggestion: `<.*>` to `<.*?>`; otherwise `s=[s,s]` will result in a greedy match of `'<_brown _little_fox >, jumped over_the_fence .the quick <_brown _little_fox >'` instead of twice the `<_brown _little_fox >`. [And thus replace the `over_the_fence` underscores.](I'm not sure if the for loop would work correct already.)

Comment: @knedlsepp - I thought I put the `?` character there for lazy evaluation.... I swear I did.  Thanks for the correction.  This is probably the 100000th post you've corrected.  I suppose half of my reputation should go to you.

Comment: More like 4th or 5th. ;-) Well, you write interesting answers, so when I stumble upon a question that I find deserves an answer and you already gave one, I will certainly have a look at your approach, occasionally finding a minor typo.

Comment: @knedlsepp I say 1000000 because it certainly does feel that way lol. A lot of the time I post code that was from a previous permutation or revision. I'll have it working on my end, but I paste in old code... Hence the typos. Either way, thank you for being diligent. It improves the quality tremendously.

Comment: Works perfectly. I guess this is as clean as it'll probably get. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Manbearpig - Yeah I can't think of any other way other than splitting up the string into `<>` substrings and working on each substring :(.  If someone does end up finding a better way, I'd love to hear about it.  BTW you're welcome!